# How to update a list item when a form action button is clicked.and is set to commit in SP 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a form with additional form action buttons along with the default save and cancel.
One is a reject button and the other is "bypass".
I have the aforementioned "bypass" to "commit"and "redirect" but I would also like it to update a field not on the form ( but same list ) to a particular choice selection value.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within SharePoint forms there is a check for a JavaScript function called PreSaveAction.  You write the function itself into your code and SharePoint knows to look for it before committing the changes.  The only problem I see is I am not sure if your code will force it to fire.  I am going to assume it will based on your description above.  Marc Anderson has a great write-up on PreSaveAction here: http://sympmarc.com/2009/05/28/validation-on-sharepoint-forms-part-four/

Once you have created the PreSaveAction function you can call your custom function to update the list.  So now you have a couple options.  You can make use of JCSOM or call a REST API using javascript as well.

To update via JSCOM, you can modify the function found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection2

A good read for updating via REST (a good practice to start getting into) can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Hope this helps.